# COPY file in bitnami prestashop docker image

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to create a custom docker image from a bitnami prestashop image.
but if i try to copy file in the dockerfile this don't work

I create a dockerfile :

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/prestashop:1.7
    
COPY modules/. /opt/bitnami/prestashop/modules
COPY themes/. /opt/bitnami/prestashop/themes
```

Then a docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_prestashop
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=bitnami
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_prestashop
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
  prestashop:
    image: custompresta:1.7.7-4
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    environment:
      - PRESTASHOP_HOST=localhost
      - PRESTASHOP_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - PRESTASHOP_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - PRESTASHOP_DATABASE_USER=bn_prestashop
      - PRESTASHOP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=bitnami
      - PRESTASHOP_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_prestashop
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - 'prestashop_data:/bitnami/prestashop'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
```

but i have an error message when i launch :

```
prestashop_1  | prestashop 08:19:04.82 INFO  ==> Running install script
prestashop_1  | prestashop 08:21:05.43 INFO  ==> Updating store settings
prestashop_1  | prestashop 08:21:05.76 INFO  ==> Persisting PrestaShop installation
prestashop_1  | rm: cannot remove '/opt/bitnami/prestashop/themes/biobanktheme/translations/en-US/en-US.en-US.xlf': Permission denied
prestashop_1  | rm: cannot remove '/opt/bitnami/prestashop/themes/biobanktheme/translations/en-US/index.php': Permission denied
prestashop_1  | rm: cannot remove '/opt/bitnami/prestashop/themes/biobanktheme/translations/fr-FR/fr-FR.fr-FR.xlf': Permission denied
prestashop_1  | rm: cannot remove '/opt/bitnami/prestashop/themes/biobanktheme/translations/fr-FR/index.php': Permission denied
deployement_prestashop_1 exited with code 1
```

But if I dont have the copy of file it work well.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried something like `RUN chmod -R 0777 /opt/bitnami/prestashop` before copy?

Comment: Thank you, it was this problem.
So I change the chmod of my folder after the copy
`USER root
RUN chmod -R 777 /opt/bitnami/prestashop/modules /opt/bitnami/prestashop/themes`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper permission for these folders:

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/prestashop:1.7

RUN chmod -R 0777 /opt/bitnami/prestashop

COPY modules/. /opt/bitnami/prestashop/modules
COPY themes/. /opt/bitnami/prestashop/themes
```